# tlmgr shows wrong package installation status

Tags: packages, texlive, tlmgr

I am using a portable XeTeX installation installed via TexLive parallel with a normal PdfLaTeX installation. I do not want to mix them up. I wanted to install some more packages for XeTeX which did not work.

When I run the command

```
tlmgr show <package>
```

`tlmgr` tells me that this package is installed. It returns something like

```
package:     ctex
category:    Package
shortdesc:   LaTeX classes and packages for Chinese typesetting
longdesc:    ctex is a collection of macro packages and document classes for LaTeX Chinese typesetting.
installed:   Yes
revision:    47595
sizes:       src: 457k, doc: 1141k, run: 717k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 2.4.14
cat-date:    2018-05-02 16:00:12 +0200
cat-license: lppl1.3c
cat-topics:  chinese book-pub class
collection:  collection-langchinese
Included files, by type:
run files:
  RELOC/tex/generic/ctex/ctexmakespa.tex
  ...
```

`tlmgr` sais that this package is installed. The problem is that I know for sure that this package is **not installed**. In fact `tlmgr` tells me that I have installed every single package which is not true. This may be true for my other installation.

Deleting the packages does not work. Also I tried the commands `tlmgr update --self`, `tlmgr update --self --all` and `tlmgr init-usertree`. I also re-downloaded the database file `texlive.tlpdb` from [CTAN](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) which didn't help too.

I am using windows so I also removed the normal PDFLaTeX installation from the `PATH` variable on my machine and I added the portable installation (which is stupid because this was the reason why I used the portable installation: **Not** to change the `PATH`). This still shows me that I have installed every package.

`tlmgr conf` does only show the paths of the portable installation. I checked the `texmf.cnf` which also contains the correct paths. When I run `kpsewhich.exe -var-value=TEXMFSYSVAR` or `kpsewhich.exe -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` I always get the correct portable XeTeX paths. I don't know why `tlmgr` is always reading the wrong TeX-directory.

So my questions are:

1. How does `tlmgr` decide whether a package is installed or not?
2. Where is `RELOC`?

Note: I always called `/path/to/the/portable/xetex/installation/bin/win32/tlmgr.bat` to make sure that I am using the correct `tlmgr` of the portable XeTeX.

Comment: For what its worth I run several tex engines and the most common issue is the path order. 1)  if I have two versions on path I cannot guarantee even if changing order which package will find another exe to run, thus only one tex engine is added at a time using separate start up scripts (same goes for perl, ghostcript etc etc.) 2) other problem is that the support texmf local may need to be changed and some of those on the machine may be found in preference to portable thus they also need scripting via a series of set texmf= difficult to know which to advise without paths but watch for appdata

Comment: There is nothing like a "portable xelatex installation" or so. Do you speak about a "portable TeX Live installation"? How did you install the "portable TeX Live installation"? `tlmgr` searches the local `texlive.tlpdb` for an entry of `ctex` to determine whether it is installed. In the portable case the tlpdb should be on `YOURINSTALLROOT/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`. `RELOC` means that packages can be installed in different `TEXMF` trees. On installation the `RELOC` will be replaced with the actual location (texmf tree).

Comment: Thank you for your ansers. Yes, I am talking about a portable TeX Live installation with XeTeX. Sorry for messing this up. So in my texlive.tlpdb there are all the packages. This makes `tlmgr` think that they are installed even tough they are not. This is my problem. Do you have any idea how I can tell `tlmgr` that they are not installed? Updating the file manually is not possible because I have **some** of the packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now. For everyone else who has a similar problem. I did the following things, I don't exactly know what fixed my problem:

1. I removed my other latex installation completely (which was something I really didn't want to do. I think this is not necessary but it's too late for me to test it).
2. *I changed the `TEXMFLOCAL` in my `texmf.cnf` from `./texmf-local` to `$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-local`. (I think this is the important thing).*
3. I ran [`tlmgr update --self`](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#update-option...-pkg) again.
4. Also there is a so called ["user mode"](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE). This allows to change the installation/sources of the packages for `tlmgr`. Maybe this may help you. You can change the path to the path where your packages actually are. I also didn't test this.

I don't know the exact reason why this was happening or how I actually fixed it. I think something with the wrong paths as @KJO mentioned.

If you have a better solution or a real explanation feel free to comment. I am still interested in what I did wrong and not too happy with my "scrappy" solution.

Comment: The default value for `TEXMFLOCAL` in the main `texmf.cnf` file (I mean `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`) is `TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT/texmf-local`. If you changed it in the top `texmf.cnf` file (I mean `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf.cnf`), then just remove the faulty line.